# How to pass parameters in to a function and display them using html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm making a shopping cart with local storage javascript and I've already asked a similar question last week where I partially solved my problem but i had to take a break and now i'm back but i've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days. I thought this would work but it doesn't.  And there aren't any errors.

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].src
    console.log(title, price, imageSrc)
    //var Item =
    //{
        //title: title,
        //price: price,
        //image: imageSrc

        //var title = title;
        //var price = price;
        //var imageSrc = imageSrc
    //}
    //var item = new Item(title, price, imageSrc)
    //var item = new Item(title, price, imageSrc)

    var product = [
        {
            "title": title,
            "price": price,
            "image": imageSrc
        }
    ]
    var pods = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item")) || []
    pods.push(product)
    localStorage.setItem("item" ,JSON.stringify(pods))
    displayCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    saveCart()
}

function loadCart() {
    let listItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"));
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        displayCart(listItems[i]);
    }
}


function displayCart(listItems) {
    //var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"))[0]
    //pods[0].title = title;
    //pods[0].price = price;
    //pods[0].imageSrc = imageSrc;
    listItems.title = title;
    listItems.price = price;
    listItems.imageSrc = imageSrc;
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-column cart-item" style="padding-top: 1%"><img class="image" style="width: 25%;" src="${imageSrc}" alt="" ><h2 style="padding-left: 5%">${title}</h2></div>
            <div class="cart-column cart-price" style="padding-top: 1%"><h2 class="price">${price}</h2></div>
            <form class="cart-column cart-quantity"><input class="quantity" type="number" id="number" value="1" style="width: 15%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 60%" /></form>
            <span style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button " type="button">Remove</button>
            </span>
        </div>`

    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].addEventListener('click', RemoveCartItem)
    saveCart()
}
```

I'm expecting display cart to be able to retrieve the title, price, imageScr and then display that in HTML on the page.

Comment: What are you expecting?  What happens (or doesn't happen) instead?

Comment: The `displayCart` expects only one parameter but you call it with 3 `displayCart(title, price, imageSrc)` in one place. Also, inside this function, you're redefining some of the `listItems` object's properties.

Comment: @BenBlank I'm expecting display cart to be able to retrieve the title, price and imageScr and display it through html on the page. And what happens is instead is nothing. I'm not sure where the error lies. And debugging hasn't gotten me anywhere which is making me think im approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: Looks like you're doing a reverse assignment. Seems to me like it should be `let title = listItems.title;` etc. rather than `listItems.title = title;`

Comment: I read your code a bit more and you are also calling `displayCart` in two different ways. `displayCart(title, price, imageSrc)`  should probably be `displayCart({ title, price, imageSrc })` (displayCart expects a single object argument, not three strings).

Comment: @BaliBalo oh man yeah I didn't even realize i was redefining the objects in the list.
I  also change the displayCart() in addToCartClicked to be displayCart({title, price, imageScr}) which is now giving me errors down at line 130 for not finding innerText of undefined. So there's obiviously more wrong things with my code.

But how does displayCart({ }) work? compared to displayCart()
Does it pass in the variables as one object? I haven't seen that anywhere else I think.

Comment: @Belonan yes, `{ title }` is a shorthand for `{ title: title }`, so it creates an inline object with all your properties. If you want your code to be compatible with old browsers you might want the full version: `displayCart({ title: title, price: price, imageSrc: imageSrc })`

Comment: It's still not outputting the right things. I'm getting undefined
https://gyazo.com/0a5dfa11e6099c18fadf60982eec634d like so